# Error while inserting data in sqlite db in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Group":
> syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE
> contact_info(Name TEXT,PhoneNumber TEXT,Email TEXT,Address TEXT,Group
> TEXT,Image BLOB);                                                                                                                                                                      > Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)                                                                                 > Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.                                                                                    > (near "Group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE
> contact_info(Name TEXT,PhoneNumber TEXT,Email TEXT,Address TEXT,Group
> TEXT,Image BLOB);)

### DatabaseOperations.java

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int database_version=1;
    public String CREATE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+ TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+ TableData.TableInfo.NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PHONE_NUMBER+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.EMAIL+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.ADDRESS+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.GROUP+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.IMAGE+" BLOB);";

//create database
    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
                super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME,null,database_version);
                Log.d("Database Operations","Database created");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       //create table
     db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database opertaions","Table created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public void putInfo(SQLiteDatabase sdb, String name, String phoneNumber,String email,String address,String group,String image)
    {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.NAME,name);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.PHONE_NUMBER,phoneNumber);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.EMAIL,email);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.ADDRESS,address);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.GROUP,group);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.IMAGE,image);

        long k= sdb.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        Log.d("Database operations","One row inserted"+k);
    }
```

Comment: `GROUP` is a [keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Either quote it everywhere you use it as a column name, or just name the column something else.

Comment: hey thanx you have solved my problem.The problem was in GROUP, its a keyword